# How does the internal circuit of the 555 works in terms of transistors

Tags: 555

I saw many explanations of 555 internal design based on block diagrams. It's good for basic understanding, but I want to understand how those internal transistor circuits make those blocks. I can see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NE555_Internal_Circuit.svg) some current mirrors there, but they looks different from examples in books.

Comment: Knowing the circuit diagram, you could of course try to build a 555 from discrete components. Or build it from a [kit](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2013/555-kit/). Then you can probe every point in the circuit with your multimeter(s) or scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the book "Designing Analog Chips" from www.designinganalogchips.com.  It is written by the designer of the 555 chip and gives all of the details of its internal circuitry.

Comment: Nice find ! This is a good example of a book to get you started on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Besides current mirrors there are many standard circuit blocks that IC designers use. Differential pairs for example which are used here for the two comparators.

The 555 is "ancient" as far as analog ICs go. In the time when it was designed circuits on ICs contained less transistors and some tricks were used here and there to keep the circuit simple and the number of transistors low. This makes the circuit a bit more complex to understand.

If you want to learn more, the subject you're looking for is "Analog IC design". There are many good books on this subject to get you started.